# Point decK to Kong Gateway running remotly

Tags: api-gateway, kong

I would like to use [decK](https://docs.konghq.com/deck/) for Kong to load and export configuration for Kong.
My plan is to install decK on the CI server and load the Kong configuration remotely to the Kong running in a Docker container within a Docker Swarm.

By default decK is pointing to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8001/
```

Looking at the [decK documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/deck/1.8.x/guides/getting-started/), I can't seem to find a way to change this and point it to something like:

```
http://my-domain:my-port/
```

How can I update this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Deck](https://docs.konghq.com/deck/1.8.x/reference/deck/)

```
  --kong-addr string               HTTP address of Kong's Admin API.
                                   This value can also be set using the 
                                   environment variable DECK_KONG_ADDR
```

Comment: is there a way to define the admin api token also?